# Return the list of elements which exceed all previous elements

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am new to Python, can anyone please point out the mistake, i have made in the code:

```
numlist = [3,2,5,5,7,6,1,8,4]
def peaks(numlist):
    exceed = []
    for elem in numlist:
        for num in exceed:
            if elem not in exceed:
                if num in exceed < elem in numlist:
                    exceed = exceed + [elem]
                    print(exceed)
```

This is what i intended to do:

peaks(numlist) = = > [3,5,7,8]

Thanks for help!!

Comment: `for num in exceed:` is never going to do anything because that list is always empty and doesn't have a chance to grow.

Comment: @Madik088 no sorry, you have several issues in here.

Comment: Thank you guys @Alex Hall and @Jean-françois-fabre!

Answer (score 5):

Your code is just overcomplex and has several issues.

- `if num in exceed < elem in numlist:` ?? you're comparing booleans... maybe you need `count` instead?
- `for num in exceed:` empty at first as Alex commented, and you test `if elem not in exceed` in this loop... overcomplicated.

Just maintain a highest element value, do it with a single loop like this:

```
numlist = [3,2,5,5,7,6,1,8,4]
maxvalue=numlist[0]-1
outlist=[]
for e in numlist:
    if e<=maxvalue:
        pass
    else:
        maxvalue = e
        outlist.append(e)

print(outlist)
```

result:

```
[3, 5, 7, 8]
```

Answer (score 0):

The first member of numlist will alwas be the first member of the answer. Any further elements will only be added to the answer when they are exceeding the maximum value of the left part of numlist:

```
numlist = [3,2,5,5,7,6,1,8,4]
print ([numlist[0]]+[n for i,n in enumerate(numlist[1:]) if n>max(numlist[:i+1])])
```